# Get image from secured web service

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services

I have a REST web service that produces a png or jpeg image. It produces the actual image, not an url that points to the image.

This service is secured using basic authentication so the client needs to provide username/password in the header.

I need to show this image in a  element inside a web page, so placing the service's URL in the 'src' attribute won't work.

I have tried the following, but I get a message saying that authentication is required:

`<img src="http://localhost:8080/app/rest/foto/100" class="photo">`

I using the $.ajax function in other service calls that return JSON and text, but I can't figure out how to do it with an image.

Comment: Please add some code to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: does your service return the url of image or the directly an image ?

Comment: I have edited the question to add further details.

Answer (score 2):

Untested Code

```
$.ajax( {

    // target url/service
    url : '/service/images?id=1',
    dataType : 'json',
    beforeSend : function(xhr) {

        // there are still other ways to do it.. i prefer crypto.js
        var bytes = Crypto.charenc.Binary.stringToBytes(username + ":" + password);
        var base64 = Crypto.util.bytesToBase64(bytes);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64);
    },
    error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

        // reset or whatever
        onError('Invalid Credentials');
},
    success : function(model) {

        // fetch the image..
        ...
    }
});
```

On client-side the idea is to craft the auth header request in a beforeSend callback.

As per [RFC 1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-11.1), the auth header value should contain the username:password as encoded (base64) string, which would result in something like the following header:

```
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
```

for base64 encoding give [crypto-js](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) a try.

Take care of using ssl.. username:passwort can be easily decoded...

----- EDIT -----

After the success event fired i would try this:

```
success : function(model) {

    // fetch the image..
    var img = $("<img />").attr('src', 'http://somedomain.com/image.jpg').load(function() {

        if (!this.complete 
            || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" 
            || this.naturalWidth == 0) {

            alert('broken image!');
        } else {

            $("#something").append(img);
        }
    });
}
```

this could work because you are still authed at the service..

futhermore you got this option:

```
var url = 'IMAGE_URL';
$.ajax({ 
    url : url, 
    cache: true,
    processData : false,
    beforeSend : function(xhr) {

        // there are still other ways to do it.. i prefer crypto.js
        var bytes = Crypto.charenc.Binary.stringToBytes(username + ":" + password);
        var base64 = Crypto.util.bytesToBase64(bytes);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64);
    },
}).always(function(){
    $("#IMAGE_ID").attr("src", url).fadeIn();
});
```

this will give a nice image fade in but could have performance glitches and relies on assumption of cache using..

another option is to use base64 encoded strings.. but you probably have to extend your backend/rest-service functionality to do it.

```
$.ajax({ 
    url : 'BASE64_IMAGE_REST_URL', 
    processData : false,
}).always(function(b64data){
    $("#IMAGE_ID").attr("src", "data:image/png;base64,"+b64data);
});
```

the ajax return value is your base64 encoded image! so it has to look like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE..."/>
```

you can try this attempt in the success method OR combined with the beforeSend().. but i never really used that before.. so.. :)

kindly

Comment: Thanks Alex. Now, my real question is what to put in the 'success' function in order to load the image bytes in a <img> element.

Comment: ok.. i tried to improve my answer.. let me know if my approaches could help you!

Comment: sorry Alex, I was absent this last few days so I didn't have time to look closely at your updates. I'll get back to this subject and write the results as soons as I have them. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax({

```
        headers: {
            'Authorization': "Basic " + btoa("username" + ":" + "P@ssw0rd"),
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
        contentType: "image/jpeg; odata=verbose",

        data1: "{ }",
        type: "GET",
        url: pictureUrl,
        success: function (model) {



            if (pictureUrl != null) {
                $("#userImage").attr('src', pictureUrl);
            } else {
                $("#userImage").attr('src', "../../assets/images/facebook- profile.jpg");
            }



        },
        error: function () {
            alert("failed");
        }
    });
```

Comment: It would be helpful to the OP if you could explain what your code is doing.